# How to express "or" in a dictionary queryset in django

Tags: django, filter, sorting

I'm filtering a big number of users based on attributes. For example, they can be filtered by minimum gpa.

So far I've been doing the following to construct my queryset-

('gpa_gt' just means that the gpa property has to be greater than whatever is the query param)

```
    if len(request.GET) != 0:
        kwargs = {}
        if request.GET['mingpa']:
            kwargs['gpa__gt'] = request.GET['mingpa']
    profiles = BlahUser.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Now, the users have a first school major attribute and a second school major attribute. If I filter by a major, I want the user to show up in the results if his first major OR his second major match any of my selections (I use a multiple select on the filtering). What I have now only works for one major-

```
    if request.GET.has_key('major'):
            kwargs['major__in'] = request.GET.getlist('major')
```

I know how to explicitly write out the query, but in my case I'm building it dynamically of sorts, and am stumped at how to do so. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borgar is definitely on the right track, but I think this is a little closer to what you are
looking for:

```
# filter for minimum GPA
gpa_filter = Q( gpa__gt=request.GET['mingpa'] )
major_filter = Q()

if request.GET.has_key('major'):
    majors = request.GET.getlist('major')
    # filter for students with first OR second major in specified majors
    major_filter = Q( first_major__in=majors| Q(second_major__in=majors)

# run filter (these are AND'ed together), so we get students that:
# 1. Have a first or second major in the specified list of majors AND
# 2. Have a GPA above the specified minimum
profiles = BlahUser.objects.get( gpa_filter, major_filter )
```

Note that you can continue to use `profiles` as a regular queryset (as in this contrived example):

```
seniors_matching_request_params = profiles.filter(status='senior')
```

So, just use Q objects where you need to, then continue to operate on the queryset as normal .

Answer (score 3):

You inclusively `or` in Django querysets with [the `Q` object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
Poll.objects.get(
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6)),
    question__startswith='Who')
```

You can operate on them like variables so you would like something like this:

```
query = Q( gpa__gt=request.GET['mingpa'] )
if request.GET.has_key('major'):
    query = query | Q( major__in=request.GET.getlist('major') )
profiles = BlahUser.objects.get( query )
```

Comment: Two questions - 
1) This would require me to convert all of my query building to use Q right? If I had more than one "greater than" queries, I'd have to say
   query = Q( gpa__gt=request.GET['mingpa'] )   query = query & Q(sat_gt=request.GET['minsat']).   This means I would need to put parenthesis around the major 'or' query. How would you do so?

2) Off the top of your head, I can use the above with object.filter right? More explicitly, BlahUser.objects.filter(query)

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think your example will include all students with a GPA above the specified minumum and also students that major in any of the specified majors, regardless of GPA, since you are combining your Q objects with 'OR'.

Comment: I figured just providing a basic example of inclusive OR + a link to the docs would be enough to get things moving. Didn't really have the patience to go for completeness this time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of this so far- (course being major)

```
     if request.GET.has_key('course'):
            extra = ['Q(first_course IN ' + request.GET.getlist('course') + ') | Q(second_course IN ' + request.GET.getlist('course') + ')']
            profiles = sumaConnectUser.objects.extra(where=[extra])
```

'course' is what we call a major. I haven't checked whether the above works but it's a start..

Help? lol